# custom templated listboxitem trigger bind to the listbox

Tags: wpf, templates, triggers, listbox

I have a class inherited from ListBox and a custom ControlTemplate for the ListBoxItems.
I want to change the ListBoxItems background if a condition is true. I tried to use DataTrigger for this. I don't want to check the condition in the ListBoxItems context object, I want to check it in the inherited ListBox class.

The question is how can I bind in the ControlTemplate the Trigger to a ListBox property, when it needs to decide the right value for each ListBoxItem in runtime?

```
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border Name="bd">
                        <TextBlock Name="lbl" Text="{Binding Path=DataChar}" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontSize="15" Margin="5"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={ RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=IsSymbolExists}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                 </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
    </Style>


public class CustomListBox : ListBox
{
 ...
     public bool IsSymbolExists
     {
          if(/*condition is true for the ListBoxItem*/)
              return true;
          return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok firstly few suggestions...

Does your custom listbox control have **only** new properties (`IsSymbolExists` etc.) and no real behavior. If so please declare them as [Attached Properties](http://eladm.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/attached-behavior/)

Secondly when this value `IsSymbolExists` becomes true for a ListBox **ALL** its items will become highlighted individually by a yellow border. This doesnt look like a well thought UI behavior. Sorry if that comes to you as a bit harsh!

Also from the binding perspective the `DataChar` property looks like a data context based property i.e.e coming from some model. If so then its binding has to be done through an `ItemTemplate` under `ListBox` and not in a `TextBlock` under `ControlTemplate` of a `ListBoxItem`. And for exactly the same reason, `DataTrigger` wont work correctly in `ControlTemplate`.

They will work correctly in `ItemTemplate`.

So to summarize, your code needs to be fixed this way...

1. You can **get rid of** `CustomListBox`. Create a boolean attached property called `MyListBoxBehavior.IsSymbolExists`. Attach it to your ListBox.
2. You should get rid of `ListBoxItem`'s `ControlTemplate`.

In ListBox take helpm from this... (this code wont compile as it is) :-)

```
    <ListBox local:MyListBoxBehavior.IsSymbolExists="{Binding WhateverBoolean}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding WhateverCollection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <Border>
               <Border.Style>
                  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                      <Style.Triggers>
                         <DataTrigger
                                Binding="{Binding
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                               Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                 AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},
                                        Path=local:MyListBoxBehavior.IsSymbolExists}"
                                Value="True">
                             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                         </DataTrigger>
                      </Style.Triggers> 
                   </Style>
                </Border.Style> 
                <TextBlock Name="lbl"
                           Text="{Binding Path=DataChar}"
                           FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                           FontSize="15"
                           Margin="5"/>
              </Border>
           </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Hope this helps.